# Add a new editText on Button press

Tags: android

I have a simple Table Layout with an empty row

```
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/range_input1" >
</TableRow>
```

I would like to add an EditText to that row when user presses a button. I am quite unsure on how to do that though. What is the proper way of doing it? So far I can only think up of two ways, first one I have the EditText in the row and just make the row hidden, or I try to create the EditText when the button is pressed.

The problem is that I have no idea how to do either option, nor could I find any tutorials on explaining how to add or hide forms.

Also I was wondering if it is possible to do slide effect.

Thanks to anyone for their help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `EditText` to the `TableRow` and make the row visibility to GONE :

```
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/range_input1" android:visibility="gone">
     <EditText />
</TableRow>
```

and in your `Button` on click listener:

```
TableRow row = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.range_input1);
row.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: Thanks so much, it worked. One comment though, I had to do View.VISIBLE. Hopefully that is correct. Thanks a lot again

Comment: @Quillion Yeap, it's `View.VISIBLE`.

Answer (score 1):

**Create a Edit Text**

```
EditText e=new EditText(this);
```

**Create a new Row**

```
TableRow t=new TableRow(this);
```

**add edit text to this row**

```
t.addView(e);
```

**now add row to table.**